# How to debug a CLR proc in VS2008?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have written a CLR proc in VS2008 and deployed to SQL 2005 DB.

I have set mode to debug and made sure my .sql script is set to run my proc.

Have deployed with permission level to External and set db to be trustworthy on.

But when I run the breakpoint is not hit and nothing seems to be happening.

What am I missing please???

Malcolm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/89cf57bb-5cf4-4405-a0c4-b4c51ad54d0c/) suggests among several things to try restarting the [Remote Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) (msvsmon.exe) on the SQL machine.

EDIT: Have you set up remote debugging of a SQL CLR Stored Procedure as per this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165051.aspx)?

Comment: Its on my local dev machine. I have restarted sql server and vs remote debugger.

Comment: FYI I rebooted my machine after enabling VS remote debugger and all came good.